# Dotnet Kafka Consumer pause and resume on schedule/on-demand

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

We have a Dotnet BackgroundService(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) running from a WebApi project. There is a Kafka Consumer(fairly new to Kafka world) running from within the ExecuteAsync method. We would like our Kafka consumer to stop/start consuming based on a schedule(stop on non-business days, run only between 8am-6pm on business days etc.). As far as we see, there are couple of ways to get this done.

1. Run the background service based on a schedule. We did some basic research and still not sure on how to achieve it. `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` seems to be hooked with application lifecycle events and doesn't like something we will be able to use for our purpose.
2. Use `consumer.pause()` and `resume()` to work based on a schedule. How can we achieve this programatically from Dotnet. We were not able to find any specific event handlers(custom schedule event) on the CosumerBuilder class.
   Any suggestions/recommendations on what is the best option here and some direction on how to achieve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to know how you ended up solving this!